# __builtin_add_overflow function supported in gcc 5 and above and what functions could replace it in gcc 4.6?

Tags: c, gcc

I built a simple applet code which has a unsupported function `__builtin_add_overflow` in my gcc version 4.6. Considering some reasons I don't want to update my gcc version. So what function in my gcc version could use to replace that function ?

Comment: duplicates: [How to check if overflow occured?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7683685/995714), [How to check if A+B exceed long long? (both A and B is long long)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15920639/995714),

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test for overflow in integer addition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422709/test-for-overflow-in-integer-addition)

Answer (score 2):

Overflow detection depends on the type of your vars.

If they are unsigned, it is sufficient to detect if the result is lower than one of its operand.

```
inline unsigned_overflow(unsigned a, unsigned b){
  return (a+b)<a;
```

If both are unsigned, oveflows can only happen if operands are of the same sign and the sign of the result will be different. So there is overflow if the sign of result is different from the sign  of its two operands.

```
inline signed_overflow(int a, int b){
  unsigned ua=a, ub=b;
  return (int)(((ua^(ua+ub))&((ub^(ua+ub)))<0  ;
```

Comment: `signed_overflow` only works with `-fwrapv`. You need to perform the potentially overflowing additions in an unsigned type.

Comment: Right. Updated the answer. Thanks for spotting this.

Comment: Now the comparison is never true because unsigned values are not negative. If you want to use the `^`/`&` hack, you really need that GCC extension.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write it on your own.  If the arguments are unsigned, it is not too hard to do (just compare if the sum is smaller than one of the addends in the larger input type).  The overflow check for signed integer arithmetic can be rather complex, particularly if all three integer types are different.  There is a GCC extension that helps somewhat: conversion from unsigned to signed types does not trigger undefined behavior, but reduces the value according to two's complement arithmetic.  So you can use this:

```
  unsigned x1 = x1;
  unsigned y1 = y1;
  bool overflow = (int) (((x + y) ^ x) & (x + y) ^ y))) < 0;
```

The book [Hacker's Delight](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1959565&seqNum=13) discusses such topics extensively.